# SQL Table with multiple rows per account

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table with account info in. so account number and then an action code etc. Each account can have many action codes in giving multiple rows. I want to select any accounts that don't have a specific code present in its history.

For example: if the code CODE001 is against account 1234 then i don't want to return a record for that account. I know I'm being thick here!

Thanks

Comment: One sugesstion for future post add your Table Schema or use http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3  for better understand to reader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have 2 tables: 1 table with account info and 1 table with accountID and actionCode?

If so, get all the accounts that are not in the inner select result:

```
SELECT * FROM accountTable WHERE accountID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT accountID FROM account_actionCode WHERE actionCode = 'CODE001')
```

Comment: Exactly right! i should have stayed at home today!! Thanks Ben! I shall where the dunces hat for the rest of the day.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE ID NOT IN
    (SELECT DISTINCT(ID) FROM accounts WHERE Code='CODE001')
```

Answer (score 0):

sNo it's not possible ( Because MySql is a linear Database which run because it has rows and columns for each entry) ... but you can lookup for Object Oriented Database.

Better way of doing this is Using two Databases :

One for Accounts, and another for ActionCodes..

the Logic can be deduced as

```
Select Acc from Accounts :
      where there does not exist a entry in ActionCodes for account Acc


SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE acc NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT ac FROM ActionCode WHERE actionCode = 'actioncode')
```